# Не работает ToolTip для неактивных Controls

Tags: c#, wpf

Здравствуйте. Не работает ToolTip для неактивных Controls в моём приложении. Например, есть Button, он неактивный (`IsEnabled = false`), у него есть ToolTip. Вопрос: возможно ли как-то сделать так, чтобы при `IsEnabled = false` и при наведении мышки на этот Button, показывалась всплывающая подсказка?

Пробовал через обработчик события MouseEnter, например, но сам обработчик срабатывает, когда у Button `IsEnabled = true`. Такое ощущение, что когда Controls имеют свойства `IsEnabled = false`, большинство свойств и обработчиков событий становятся тоже неактивными.

Comment: Уважаемый, честно... Вам приятно это читать? Один сплошной текст, могли бы постараться, абзацы сделать, отступы итд...

Comment: У вас ощущения правильные, если контрол сделан недоступным, то есть у него `IsEnabled = true`, то все интерактивные действия с ним невозможны.

Comment: @Bulson Скорее всего вы имели в виду `IsEnabled = false`. А так да, я понял ваш комментарий. Благодарю за ответ.

Comment: Поместите поверх своего контрола другой прозрачный и задайте тултип ему. Оберните свой контрол чем-нибудь и этому чему-нибудь задавайте тултип. Способы не проверял

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь присоединённым атрибутом [`ToolTipService.ShowOnDisabled`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.tooltipservice.showondisabled(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
<Button ToolTipService.ShowOnDisabled="True" ToolTip="Привет валет!" IsEnabled="False">
    Привет
</Button>
```

Получается:

[image: пардон мадам]

Comment: Да, у меня также получилось. Всё-таки это возможно сделать. Благодарю за подсказку. Но у меня остался вопрос по поводу XAML разметки. В вашем примере вы используете класс `ToolTipService` и его свойство `ShowOnDisabled`. Как мне интуитивно понимать, какие ещё другие классы с его свойствами я могу использовать для Controls? Есть ли какие-то отличительные признаки?

Comment: @Cuurjol: Хороший вопрос! Мне подсказала Visual Studio: я начал набирать `tooltip`, и она вывела подсказку `ToolTipService`. А там я уже нашёл свойство, похожее по названию на нужное, и проверил, что оно работает как надо.

Comment: У меня почему-то для конкретного `Button` выводились только свойство `ToolTip` и два обработчика события (`ToolTipClosing` и `ToolTipOpening`), так как для любого Controls указываем либо свойство, либо обработчик события (классы почему-то не ищет). Я возможно не там вводил слово `ToolTip`. Тем не менее могу предположить, что в XAML разметке можно использовать только те классы, у которых свойства — это именно присоединённые свойства, а не обычные. Но я не уверен.

Comment: @Cuurjol: Я точно не знаю всех правил, да они и меняются. Но в крайнем случае можно спросить на StackOverflow :)